# Graphql, react-apollo how to transfer variable to query at loading component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, graphql, react-apollo

I have a simple react component that must load data from server when user ask it. Problem is that i don't know how to transfer dynamic variable speakerUrl and access it in before component load state. Sure i can access it from `this.props.params`, but component is not loaded and i can't access it when i make a graphql query. Query - `QuerySpeaker` is working fine when i manualy set url variable.

**Router**

```
<Route path="/speaker/:speakerUrl" component={SpeakerPage} />
```

**Component - SpeakerPage**

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

import { QuerySpeaker } from '../redux/graphql/querys';

class SpeakerPage extends React.Component {
    render( ) {
        console.log( this.props );
        return (
            <div className="ui container">
                <div className="ui grid">
                    <div className="row">
                        Hello
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default graphql(QuerySpeaker, {
     options: ({ url }) => ({ variables: { url } }) <- here is my problem, how can i set this url variable?
})( SpeakerPage );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the `react-apollo` [documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#graphql-options), the argument passed to the `options` function is the props object passed to the component. When `react-router` renders your component, it passes it the `params` as a prop. That means that `params` should be a property of the object passed to the `options` function.

```
export default graphql(QuerySpeaker, {
  options: (props) => ({ variables: { url: props.match.params.speakerUrl } })
})( SpeakerPage );
```

Comment: Not very obvious in the docs considering how frequent this use case comes up in dev. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Paul. I resolved a similar problem I had! Upvote from me.

Comment: In think that in react router v4, you should use the match property: props.match.params.speakerUrl

Comment: @yonih Yes, you're right. I wrote this while v4 was still in beta (or maybe alpha) and I believe that the API was slightly different at the time. Will update my answer.