# Apollo: Defining `params` in withData?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollostack

I'm learning the latest Apollo libs. This `withData` code is adapted from the Githunt-React Apollo demo:

```
const withData = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options: ({ params }) => {
        console.log(params);

        return {
            variables: {
                "fromID": Meteor.userId(),
                "toID": `${params.toID}`,
            },
        };
    },
});
```

`params` is coming in `undefined`. The Apollo docs don't [seem](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html) to say where it is defined.

Looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026900/graphql-react-apollo-how-to-transfer-variable-to-query-at-loading-component-sta), it appears that `params` is supposed to contain the `props` passed to the component.  But it always comes in `undefined` here.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. `{params}` (in curly braces) had to be changed to `props` (no curly braces):

```
const withData = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options: (props) => {
        console.log(props);

        return {
            variables: {
                "fromID": Meteor.userId(),
                "toID": props.toID,
            },
        };
    },
});
```

What I don't yet understand is, why does the Githunt-React Apollo demo code, have it in curly braces?

If you know, please post your response as an answer, and upon confirmation I will mark it as the accepted answer to this question. :)